# I have two questions about google translation api

Tags: google-translate

The first problem is The original language is english, "CORN STARCH PROCESSING LINE" is translated into Russian with a neural machine. The result is "ЛИНИЯ ОБРАБОТКИ КУХНЯ", which is larger difference from the original language. And the second problem is  the original language is english, "SULLAIR COALESCING FILTER 02250153-324", translated into Arabic with the neural machine, the result is "SULLAIR COALESCING FILTER 02250153-324", not Arabic.how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please post the exact way of how you used/accessed `Google Translate API` (source code, etc)? That way others can check quickly where things might've gone wrong.

Comment: If you need the translations to be perfect, have a human do them. AI translation has a long, long way to go before it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `Russian` translation, the Cloud Translation API is giving a result as much accurate as it is possible. Those results are being constantly improved and updated.

For the `Arabic` translation part, there seems to be an issue with using the `-` symbol in the numbers. Because if you remove it or use any other symbol then the words will be translated to `Arabic` as expected.

I have created an issue tracker for that, you can [follow this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123183428) to get updates on the fix. Keep in mind that there is no ETA on when the fix will be ready, so as a work around for now, just replace the `-` symbol with `_` symbol and the words will be translated to `Arabic`.